# does not display css content through thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, css, thymeleaf

i have css files:
main.css

```
h1 { 
    color: red;
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Drink Shop</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="@{/css/main.css}"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Wellcome</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

everything looks good, but the red color of h1 text: wellcome does not show up
I using thymeleaf, spring boot.
Maybe I should add some dependence in pom.xml?

hierarchy

[image]

Comment: Can you post your Controller code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css" th:href="@{/css/main.css}" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: Try to add /static/css to above link